# How to get context for the parameter of UIGraphicsPushContext?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

As the apple's document said, UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext can only be used in drawRect method.
If you want to use it in another place, you have to push a context before.

Now I want to use UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext to get a context in my own method called render.
How can I get a context to push?

Can I get the context in drawRect and save it in a non-local variable? 
And push it in another method, then use UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext to get it to use.
If so, why need I push it and get it again? I can use the non-local variable directly.

Comment: Is your method `render` called, directly or indirectly, by your `drawRect` method?

Comment: The method `render` has nothing to do with `drawRect`. I just call `render` per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `setNeedsDisplay` of the view that you need redrawn on timer, and have its `drawRect` call your `render` (instead of calling your `render` on timer directly). This way you would avoid unusual manipulations with your CG Context, and prevent rendering when the rectangle has been scrolled off the screen.

Edit:
You use UIGraphicsPushContext and UIGraphicsPopContext when you want a specific context to become the context on which UI Kit operates. My initial understanding of what they do was incorrect (I'm relatively new to iOS development myself). For example, there are operations (e.g. some operations setting a color or other drawing parameters) that operate implicitly on the current context. If you set up a context for, say, drawing on a bitmap, and then you want to use an operation that modifies the state of the current context (i.e. an operation that modifies the context parameters, but does not take a specific context reference as a parameter), you push the bitmap context to make it current, perform the operation that implicitly references it, and pop the context right back.

Special thanks go to rob mayoff for explaining this to me.

Comment: Yes, what you said works well.Thank you. But I still don't understand the question in the title and when/how to use UIGraphicsPushContext. Could you please explan it?

Comment: @理想评论学派 Sure, I added a brief explanation.

Comment: This discussion of UIGraphicsPushContext and UIGraphicsPopContext is wrong.  Those functions are intended to change the graphics context on which UIKit objects (e.g. `[[UIBezierPath ...] fill]`) and functions (e.g. `UIRectFill`) operate.  If you want to save and restore the state (e.g. fill color and stroke color) of the current graphics context, use `CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())` and `CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())`.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks for explaining this! I modified the answer. I'll check my code tomorrow to see if my use of push/pop context has been incorrect. Thank you very much!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Your answer still seems to be talking about the gstate in the latter half of that paragraph. You would push a context when you want “the operation that modifies the current context” to modify *a completely separate context* (the one you push). Think of a “context” as a drawing destination: Pushing a context means “draw here instead until I say otherwise”. The graphics state is the collection of drawing parameters that affect drawing within a single context.

Comment: @PeterHosey Yes, this was precisely my new understanding of it after Rob's explanation. Perhaps the way I put it into words was not perfect - I tried to change it once more, but if you think it's still not clear, I'll gladly approve your edits. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To get a CGContext into which you can draw in a render call outside of a drawRect, you can allocate your own graphics bitmap, and create a context from that bitmap.  Then you can draw to that context anytime.

If you wish to display that context after drawing into it, you can use it to create an image, and then draw that image to a view during the's UIView's drawRect.  Or, alternatively, you could assign that image to a view's CALayer's contents, which should be flushed to the display sometime during the UI run loop's processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CGContextSaveCGState` and `CGContextRestoreCGState` to push and pop your current graphic context.  At this [link](http://www.invasivecode.com/blog/archives/1137) a simple example.

Comment: No, `SaveGState` and `RestoreGState` push and pop the graphics state, not a graphics context. A graphics context contains a stack of graphics states; saving and restoring gstate happens within a single context.